# How can i get all months With between two dates

Tags: php, mysql

i have this query that get all regsiterd data between this two dates

```
SELECT date as date_month, status FROM tbl_reports WHERE status != 0 AND (date BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31') GROUP BY MONTH(date)
```

result

```
   date_month    
   2017-04-19
   2017-05-24
   2017-06-26
   2017-07-01
```

but how i can get the result even if there is no regsitered input in the other months

want result

```
  Date_month
  2017-01-01
  2017-02-01
  2017-03-01  - it will give this value if there is no such data in this month
  2017-04-19  - i will get the input date from database
  ''   '' ''
  2017-12-31
```

is it possible ? or i need some php code to manipulate this data?
thank you in advance for my answering my question.. :)

Comment: first of all: your query is not correct. There is no agregation function in the SELECT part of your query. It seems like you are misusing group by to get a sort of distincting side effect, selection only one date in every month?

Comment: as for the question itself: I think you have to look in the way of creating a table having 2 columns: year and month. And you fill that table from 2017 - 1 until 2027-12 or what ever dates would be relevant to you.
Then you could join dates in that table into your current query

Comment: ohh i see.. thank you sr.. your right but if i need to select every data that in one month has and give only one data to the months that there is no value (a value of every first day of their month.) is it possible.. and i will remove my Group by function right? and use order by?

Comment: or instead of using date value from my database how i will print all months frist day. between 2017-01-01 AND 2017-12-31
result is = `january = 2017-01-01` `February= 2017-02-01` and so on till  `December = 2017-12-01`

Comment: I put it in an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an extra table, named datehelper. Provide it with 2 columns: year and month. And fill those with year: 2017 until 2027 and 1 / 12 for the months.

```
SELECT 
   datehelper.year,
   datehelper.month,
   r.status
FROM datehelper
LEFT JOIN tbl_reports r ON MONTH(r.date) = datehelper.month
     AND YEAR(r.date) = datehelper.year AND status != 0
WHERE  (datehelper.year = '2017')
ORDER BY datehelper.year, datehelper.month
```

I see you would get duplicates on the left joined part if there are more records there in a certain month.
What status would you expect? Let's think there are records with status 0 (excluded) status = 1, and status = 2

datehelper:

```
   year  month    
   2017   1
   2017   2
   2017   3
   2017   4
    ...
   2017   11
   2017   12
   2018   1
    ...
```

Comment: how do i put the months?  i got little confuse on 1/12 or its 1 to 12? sory xD

Comment: oh w8 hahaha i will put it now

Comment: made a change to the query: status <> 0 now in on-clause of join